# Unable to open project in VisualStudio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I created a SilverLight solution in Visual Web Developer Express 2010.  Now, my system got installed with Visual Studio 2010 Professional.  On opening the existing express solution, I got the below error:

Unable to open project. An update to Microsoft Visual Studio is required to support the targeted version of SilverLight.  Download the update at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=168436

It takes to install the add-on Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010.  My question is 'Why itz not part and parcel of professional edition?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the silverlight tools for VS2010 were released very shortly after VS2010 went RTM.  Silverlight is a separate technology that isn't dependent on Visual Studio.  It's developed by a different group and they have separate release schedules.

Comment: Also worth noting that Silverlight 4 tooling was included into VS2010 SP1.  Silverlight 5 is still a separate release.